# Can't change the y-axis scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I plotted data from different Heat results. However, the y-axis is always scaled from lowest to highest value found in the according value in the dataset.
I want to change the scale so that the y-axis indicates from 4.0 to 10.0

I put in ylim but this returns "Discrete value supplied to continuous scale"

```
ggplot(WDF, aes(x = Episode, y = Rating, color = Rating)) +  
  geom_point() +
  ylim(4.0, 10.0)+   
  geom_jitter()+     
  facet_grid(. ~ Season)
```

Original Code without Error but also without correct Y axis scale

```
ggplot(WDF, aes(x = Version, y = Cells, color = Rating)) +    
  geom_jitter()+ facet_grid(. ~ Heat)
```

scale y-axis from 4.0 to 10.0

This is my result:

[image: Plot Result]

Comment: What is the source of your data? Can you provide a reproducible code sample?

Comment: From the looks of your legend, it seems like Rating is an ordered factor, not a continuous value. Try converting it to a numeric type first if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

Your current data may look like this:

```
library(tidyverse) 
WDF <- data.frame(  
    Rating = factor(round(runif(90, min = 5, max = 9.6), 1)),
    Episode = runif(90, min = 0.1, max = 15.9),
    Season = seq(1:9)
)
```

`Rating` is a `factor` variable. When you run:

```
ggplot(WDF, aes(x = Episode, y = Rating, color = Rating)) + 
  geom_point() + ylim(4.0, 10.0)+ geom_jitter()+ facet_grid(. ~ Season)
```

get `error:  Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`.

Now, change `Rating` from `factor` to `numeric`:

```
WDF <- WDF %>% mutate(Rating_1 = as.numeric(as.character(Rating)))
```

Please note: `as.character()` here is important. Without it, you will get numeric but wrong numbers. You could try without it to see the difference.

Then, run your original code with new variable `Rating_1`:

```
ggplot(WDF, aes(x = Episode, y = Rating_1, color = Rating_1)) + 
  geom_point() + ylim(4.0, 10.0)+ geom_jitter()+ facet_grid(. ~ Season)
```

To produce the following: 
[image]